# Как в ViewPager подгружать все фрагменты

Tags: android, android-viewpager

`ViewPager` подгружает боковые фрагменты, мне нужно чтоб он подгружал все фрагменты что есть, как такое реализовать? (нужно для реализации ImageSlider'а)

Comment: android studio ничего не подгружает, это IDE для того, чтобы код написать. Заголовок должен содержать краткую суть проблемы, а не близкие к ней по смыслу отдельные слова.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> По умолчанию `ViewPager` загружает элемент, находящийся на экране, а
>   также по одному соседнему элементу в каждом направлении, чтобы отклик
>   на жест прокрутки был немедленным. Количество загружаемых соседних
>   страниц можно настроить вызовом [setOffscreenPageLimit(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)).

*стр 238 - Филлипс Б., Стюарт К., Марсикано К.
Android. Программирование для профессионалов. 3-е изд.*

Пример

```
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
```